# Unable to install kraken (image optimizer)

Tags: python, image-processing, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, kraken-image-optimizer

I want to install **kraken** in my anaconda. So I followed this command got from [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/kraken/) -

```
pip install kraken
```

But I end up with an error and that is -

```
Collecting kraken
Using cached kraken-2.0.8-py3-none-any.whl (643 kB)
Collecting python-bidi
  Downloading python_bidi-0.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (30 kB)
Collecting protobuf>=3.0.0
  Downloading protobuf-3.12.2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (1.0 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.0 MB 30 kB/s
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch>=1.0.0 (from kraken) (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.1.2.post2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch>=1.0.0 (from kraken)
```

I,ve also tried the instruction from [anaconda](https://anaconda.org/bioconda/kraken) -

```
conda install -c bioconda kraken
```

But this time I've got -

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

    - kraken

Current channels:

    - https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/win-64
    - https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/noarch
    - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
    - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
    - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
    - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
    - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
    - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

All these command I've eneterd is in **Anaconda Prompt.** So please help me through on how can I install kraken. TIA.

Comment: Note that `bioconda::kraken` is a bioinformatics tool for studying metagenomics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The GitHub repository](https://github.com/mittagessen/kraken#installation) has instructions for installing through Conda. It shows creating a new env, which generally is good practice.

**Non-CUDA Version**

```
$ wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mittagessen/kraken/master/environment.yml
$ conda env create -f environment.yml
```

**CUDA Version**

```
$ wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mittagessen/kraken/master/environment_cuda.yml
$ conda env create -f environment_cuda.yml
```

Note the `--name` flag can be used to specify an env name other than their default (`kraken`).

#### Install in Existing Environment

Technically, one can also use a YAML to install into an existing env. However, since it involves a `pip`-based installation, it is not recommended to install this to the **base** env (see [Using Pip in a Conda Environment](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#pip-in-env)).

```
conda env update -n my_env -f environment.yml
```

Comment: From the [github link] (https://github.com/mittagessen/kraken#installation) I've got this -    **kraken only runs on Linux or Mac OS X.   Windows is not supported.**   Is that a reason for my installation problem?

Comment: @mefahimrahman yes - sorry I did not notice you were working in **win-64**. Not sure what the best route is then - perhaps [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10)?